# ¿Como podría este código retornar False?

Tags: python, funciones

Esta función indica si un código número es un cuadrado perfecto, pero no sé como hacer que retorne False, pues la verificación se hace dentro de un bucle. Funciona para la mayoria de cuadrados perfectos. También me encarge de manejar algunas excepciones. ¿Me ayudarían a optimizarlo?

```
def es_cuadrado(n):    
    if n < 0:
        return False
    if n == 0:
        return True
    if n == 3:
        return False
    if n == 26:
        return False
    for i in range(n-1):
        var = i**2
        if var == n:
            return True
```

Comment: `else: return False`??

Comment: Ya lo inttente. El problema que si en una iteración el número verificado (var) no es la raiz cuadrada de n, va a dar False, incluso si el for en algún punto iba a dar True de igual manera. O por lo menos, eso es lo que noté.

Comment: Pues si existe otra excepción donde deba dar true usa un elif

Comment: @Siderius'Nuncius por que hacer un `for` si se puede comprobar sacando la raiz cuadrada?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente agrega una cláusula `return false` al final de la función. Si alcanza esa línea, es porque el número no cumple las condiciones. Cualquiera de los `return` anteriores impedirán que esa línea se ejecute, pues allí terminará la ejecución de la función.

En código, se vería así:

```
def es_cuadrado(n):    
    if n < 0:
        return False
    if n == 0:
        return True
    if n == 3:
        return False
    if n == 26:
        return False
    for i in range(n-1):
        var = i**2
        if var == n:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta de [jachguate](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/460824/como-podr%c3%ada-este-c%c3%b3digo-retornar-false/460840#460840) me parece la más adecuada para tu pregunta puntual de *¿Cómo hacer que tire `false`?*.

Por otro lado, para optimizar creo que es más sencillo hacer la raíz cuadrada del número y ver si dicho resultado tiene decimales o no, para esto podemos elevar el número a 1/2 (raíz cuadrada) y luego utilizar el  operador módulo `%` para ver que el número sea un entero (no exista residuo de una división por la unidad):

```
def es_cuadrado(n): 
    return (n**0.5%1)==0
```